# Join two tables and divide value equally

Tags: sql, postgresql

**[DB-Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=b2b86608acbd80ead884b5acac8bc450)**

```
/* Table Costs */
CREATE TABLE costs (
    id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    date DATE,
    costs_per_day DECIMAL
);

INSERT INTO costs
(date, costs_per_day)
VALUES 
('2020-01-01', '400'),
('2020-01-02', '400'),
('2020-01-03', '400'),
('2020-01-04', '400');


/* Table Sales Place */
CREATE TABLE sales_place (
    id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    event_date DATE,
    country VARCHAR,
    sales_channel VARCHAR
);

INSERT INTO sales_place
(country, sales_channel)
VALUES 
('DE', 'online'),
('DE', 'store'),
('NL', 'online'),
('NL', 'store'),
('FR', 'online'),
('FR', 'store');
```

**Expected Result:**

```
date_list    |   country    |   sales_channel   |      costs_per_day        |
-------------|--------------|-------------------|---------------------------|------
2020-01-01   |     DE       |      online       |      66.66  (=400/6)      |
2020-01-01   |     DE       |      store        |      66.66  (=400/6)      |
2020-01-01   |     NL       |      online       |      66.66  (=400/6)      |
2020-01-01   |     NL       |      store        |      66.66  (=400/6)      |
2020-01-01   |     FR       |      online       |      66.66  (=400/6)      |
2020-01-01   |     FR       |      store        |      66.66  (=400/6)      |
-------------|--------------|-------------------|---------------------------|------
2020-01-02   |     DE       |      online       |      66.66  (=400/6)      |
2020-01-02   |     DE       |      store        |      66.66  (=400/6)      |
2020-01-02   |     NL       |      online       |      66.66  (=400/6)      |
2020-01-02   |     NL       |      store        |      66.66  (=400/6)      |
2020-01-02   |     FR       |      online       |      66.66  (=400/6)      |
2020-01-02   |     FR       |      store        |      66.66  (=400/6)      |
-------------|--------------|-------------------|---------------------------|------ 
2020-01-03   |     DE       |      online       |      66.66  (=400/6)      |
2020-01-03   |     DE       |      store        |      66.66  (=400/6)      |
2020-01-03   |     NL       |      online       |      66.66  (=400/6)      |
2020-01-03   |     NL       |      store        |      66.66  (=400/6)      |
2020-01-03   |     FR       |      online       |      66.66  (=400/6)      |
2020-01-03   |     FR       |      store        |      66.66  (=400/6)      |
-------------|--------------|-------------------|---------------------------|------
2020-01-04   |     DE       |      online       |      66.66  (=400/6)      |
2020-01-04   |     DE       |      store        |      66.66  (=400/6)      |
2020-01-04   |     NL       |      online       |      66.66  (=400/6)      |
2020-01-04   |     NL       |      store        |      66.66  (=400/6)      |
2020-01-04   |     FR       |      online       |      66.66  (=400/6)      |
2020-01-04   |     FR       |      store        |      66.66  (=400/6)      |
```

---

I want to combine the tables `costs` and `sales_place` so the `costs_per_day` are divided equally to each `country` and `sales_channel`.

I tried a view ways but could not make it work so far:

```
SELECT 
c.date AS date_list,
t1.country,
t1.sales_channel,
c.costs_per_day
FROM costs c
LEFT JOIN

  (SELECT
  sp.country AS country,
  sp.sales_channel AS sales_channel
  FROM sales_place sp
  ORDER BY 1,2) t1 ON t1.country = c.country

ORDER BY 1,2,3;
```

How do I need to change the query to get the expected result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your expected output looks to just be a cross join.  We can use `COUNT()` as an analytic function to normalize the costs per day.

```sql
SELECT
    c.date,
    sp.country,
    sp.sales_channel,
    c.costs_per_day / COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY c.date) AS costs_per_day
FROM costs c
CROSS JOIN sales_place sp
ORDER BY
    c.date;
```

Here to generate the costs per day we just divide each date's cost by the number of records for that day *after* the cross join has happened.  Here is your updated DB Fiddle:

### Demo

Comment: Just for my own documentation: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=09c4bae754f3f55ed612c40ec3cb7b3f